# How do I apply styling to sorted columns in Angular ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, styling, angular-ui-grid

I have a ui-grid with some narrow columns and when I apply a sort to these columns, the little arrow that indicates the sort and its direction doesn't show. So I'd like to be able to style the column cells, or just the column header, according to the column sort status (asc, desc and none). Is this possible?

Here's an example screenshot showing three sorted columns (also note the menu icon is kind of broken, but that's another issue):

[image: Three columns sorted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'headerCellClass' option in your 'columnDefs'.

Documentation is here : http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/115_headerCellClass

In your case it would be like :

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      { 
        field: 'company',
        headerCellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
          if (col.sort.direction) {
            return 'red';
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.core.on.sortChanged( $scope, function( grid, sort ) {
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
      })
    }
  };
```

Working Plunker is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/ifQlqkGAEdeELbMqozVE?p=preview

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that's exactly what I was after. I have no idea why I couldn't find that in the docs for myself. I added a bit to your snippet of code in case the plunker and/or docs are down (unlikely I know, but no harm in rounding out your example here). :-)